# How to generate ladder operators for an arbitrary Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

How to generate ladder operators for an arbitrary Hamiltonian? i.e. for a power-law potential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Hamiltonians will not have ladder operators. From the point of view of the Schroedinger equation it is a question as to which of them can be factorized as $H=Q^\dagger Q$ for $Q$ a first-order differential operator. This possibility was exhaustively explored  by Infeld and Hull in the 1950's (I. Infeld and T.E. Hull, Rev. Mod. Phys. 23, 21 (1951).). I Googled for a more up-to-date refeence and found arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9812003.

Another source of such techniques (which overlaps with the first) is given by looking up  what is called "Supersymmetric Quantum Mechanics". Here a good reference is the Physics Report (Vol 251 (1995) pp 267-385) entitled       "Supersymmetry and Quantum Mechanics" by Fred Cooper Avinash Kare and Uday Sukhatme. It should be available online if you have access from a University account.

Comment: Actually lots of Hamiltonians have ladder operators, v.g. $su(2)$, $su(3)$ and indeed pretty much any system for which the Hamiltonian in an element of a Lie algebra.  Granted, it may not be so easy to identify the algebra, and the number of examples for specific case power laws is *very* limited.